# How can I use `phone number` and `otp` in "django-rest-framework-simplejwt" instead of `username` and `password` to generate token?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

#urls.py

**I just want to know how to set custom fields, for e.g instead of 'username' and 'password' can i get 'phone_number'  and otp**

````
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . import api_views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (TokenObtainPairView,TokenRefreshView,)


urlpatterns = [

    # Api Urls
    path('api/',api_views.getRoutes,name="api"),
    path('api/register',api_views.registerPatient,name="signup"),
    path('api/patient/',api_views.getPatients,name="patients"),
    path('api/create/',api_views.CreatePatient,name="create"),
    path('api/patient/<str:pk>/',api_views.getPatient,name="patient"),
    path('api/update/<str:pk>/',api_views.updatePatient,name="update"), 
    path('api/delete/<str:pk>/',api_views.deletePatient,name="delete"),
    path('api/login/',TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),

    path('api/doctor/',api_views.doctorRegister,name="doctorreg"),
    
    path('api/getroutes/', api_views.getRoutes, name='getroutes'),

    path('api/sotp/',api_views.send_otp,name="sotp"),
    path('api/votp/',api_views.verify_otp,name="votp"),
    path('api/signup/',api_views.registerPatient,name="signup"),
]```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own **TokenSerializer** and **TokenView** classes, that inherit from **TokenObtainPairSerializer** and **TokenObtainPairView** and in which you can define token claims. More info [here](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html#customizing-token-claims)

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['phone_number'] = user.phone_number
        # ...

        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

and in the URL

```
path('api/login/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

Comment: i just want change fields username to phone_number and password to otp can you please help how to this its been 2 days i am not getting any solution